# Merge [cakephp-appmodel] and [cakephp-model]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are numerous tags for the php framework [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) - but two tags related to the use of models: [cakephp-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) and [cakephp-appmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel) - the latter is a problem.

[AppModel](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Model/AppModel.php) is a class in CakePHP, it is the parent class for all models, and so it's confusing to have a tag related to this class whilst the questions that are tagged with it are not related to this class. It's also unecessary as there is only one type of models in the CakePHP framework and they are simply: Models.

How to I propose/achieve merging these two tags?

Full disclosure: I am a core developer for this framework :)

Comment: I totally agree that appmodel is not very useful and too narrow. It should all be merged into cakephp-model.

Comment: Considering cakephp-model is only on one question, do we really need a merge?

Comment: @Wooble not sure if that's a technical question (?) I can retag things manually if appropriate - the main point is the "wrong tag" is being used and it should be replaced and deleted.

Comment: Actually, it looks like cakephp-model was the victim of an ill-advised mass-tag to cakephp-appmodel in the past. Ugh.

Comment: _5 years later_ .... which tag do you prefer today?

Comment: An year after my comment (which I think was enough time to decide) ... I'm going ahead with the majority for now, feel free to ping if you want the direction of the synonym to be reversed.

Comment: `cakephp-appmodel - the latter is a problem.` I don't know what was unambiguous about this (the first comment was also made by a core dev) - yes please, rename that to `cakephp-model`